# Extract data in between characters within string in Zapier using python

Tags: python, zapier

I am working to extract the twitter handle of a user from a string of text.

The text is always in this format:

SomeText (@handle)

BTW, I am running this as a step in a multi-step zap.
My idea was to use python to extract everything in between the parenthesis using this code:

```
s = input_data['s']
return s[s.find("(")+1:s.find(")")]
```

I defined s in my zap per the documentation, see screen shot:

[image]

I am getting the following error:

'str' object has no attribute 'copy'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that data returned from a Python Code step must be JSON serializable.

try this:

```py
s = input_data['s']
return {'handle': s[s.find("(")+1:s.find(")")]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression, as in:

```
import re

text1 = "SomeText (@handle)"
text2 = "1 (bla bla) article #author: #something (@handle)"

res = re.search(r"\(([^)]*)\)$", text2)
res.groups()[0]
```

The result is '@handle' for both text1 and text2.

Comment: thanks because I am using zapier, I need to work with the input data as shown in the image above, doing as you suggested, I get an error 'text' is not defined

Comment: Oops, forgot to include 'text' in the code snippet. If, in your code, you get the text as s, just replace 'text2' in res.serch with 's'.